# Specify php extension within docker-compose.yml

Tags: php, docker-compose, dockerfile

How do I specify php extension within my `docker-compose.yml`?

I use version 3 to list all the images like *nginx*, *mariadb*, *php-fpm*, etc. I rather simplify it within a single file instead create more dir and file for Dockerfile.